# Could react-native implement resident notification?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Could react-native implement resident notice like this and notice can be handled?

[image]

Comment: There is no concept of resident notice. Can you pleas elaborate a bit more on what you want? from the image i am not able to understand your problem

Comment: @Rigorousimplementation when i click notification icons, i can receive events.